# Is there a way to find where PATH was set?

Tags: bash, unix, command-line-interface

When I echo $PATH in UNIX I get this:

```
   /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.3.9/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin
```

Is there a way to find where

```
/usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.3.9/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin
```

was set?  I don't remember setting that.

I checked .profile, .bashrc, and .bash_profile and didn't see any PATH declarations in any of them.  So how do I find where someone put it?

EDIT: relevant output of "bash -x -l"

```
+ '[' -x /usr/libexec/path_helper ']'
++ /usr/libexec/path_helper -s
+ eval 'PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.3.9/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin:/Applications/dev/Apache-Derby/db-derby-10.12.1.1-bin/bin";' export 'PATH;'
++ PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.3.9/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin:/Applications/dev/Apache-Derby/db-derby-10.12.1.1-bin/bin
++ export PATH
```

Comment: `/etc/environment` maybe? or `/etc/profile`

Comment: @rbm  not in either of those

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/813/how-to-determine-where-an-environment-variable-came-from

Comment: @AndyRay  "env" doesn't really help me as I'm looking for the source to a PATH concatenation.  I need to find what file is being called which sets that maven path

Comment: $PATH is an environment variable

Comment: @AndyRay  Right.  And I need to found which file is setting the environment variable for maven.  "env" doesn't show me that

Comment: Try running `bash -x -l` to see what gets run when you login.  You should be able to detect what sets your PATH when you login — there may be multiple scripts and/or programs that are used.  Be prepared to be horrified.  When you're done looking, use `exit` to get back to your original shell (and `set +x` to turn off the tracing.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler  I did what you said, see my main edit.  What do the plus's on the side mean?

Comment: They represent the nesting level at which the input is working.  One `+` refers to lines directly in `.profile` or whatever is currently being parsed; two `+`'s refer to a file included (`.` or `source`) in that file, etc.  Roughly.  Anyway, you now know which program is setting PATH; you can chase down what it does (`man path_helper` works on a Mac; it may do on Linux too — the manual section is 8 on Mac).  From there, you can find the line in `/etc/paths.d` or wherever that is adding it for you.

Comment: @vkapustin this question is an exact duplicate of the one I linked to. There's no direct way to do what you're asking. All the options are covered in the other thread.

Answer (score 4):

Start your shell with the `-x` option; the output will show each command that is executed, which includes the `source`/`.` commands that will show you which files are sourced. You'll be able to identify file contains the assignment to `PATH` of interest.

Comment: Sorry for newb question, but how to start shell with -x option?

Comment: Just run `bash -x`, or `bash -lx` to start a login shell. (Each will source a slightly different set of initialization files, so you may need to try both before you find the answer you want.)

Comment: gotcha.  I have no idea what I'm looking at though (see my main edit above).  What do the "+" on the side mean?  Is there a way to see the start/end of files it's parsing through?

Comment: It's not as clear as it could be, but what's happening is some file (mostly likely `/etc/profile`) is executing something like `eval $(/usr/libexec/path_helper -s)`; `path_helper` outputs the line `PATH=...`, consisting of directory names that it finds in `/etc/paths` and files in `/etc/paths.d`. `eval` executes that line to actually set the variable.

Answer (score 1):

`man bash` lists

- /etc/profile
- /etc/bash.bashrc
- ~/.bash_profile
- ~/.bashrc

As the files it reads on startup. PATH will be modified in one of those, in a file referenced in one of those (or referenced in a file referenced...), or will be set for the login process before your shell is started.